# OneToMany: hibernate tries to nullify external reference instead of deleting whole child

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity "BigList" containing a list of elements:

```
  @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true )
  @Cascade( { CascadeType.ALL } )  
  @JoinColumn( name = "ID_LIST", referencedColumnName="ID", updatable=true, insertable=true )
  @OrderBy( value="position asc")
  List<BigListElem> elements;
```

While a BigListElem has this reference:

```
  @ManyToOne( optional=false )
  @NotFound( action=NotFoundAction.EXCEPTION )
  @JoinColumn( name="ID_LIST", nullable=false, updatable=true, insertable=true  )
  private BigList list;
```

Now, if I delete one single element of this list and call merge() method (thus updating) I get the following exception:

```
impossible update ("DBNAME"."BIG_LIST_ELEM"."ID_LIST") to NULL
```

In other words instead of deleting the children it tries to set the external reference to null, leading to exception because "nullable" is set to false. 
This is correct, because external reference cannot be null...problem is that I am not asking to set this reference to null but deleting the whole element!

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Usually FK constraints on children elements are nullable, because hibernate if I remember correctly does the deletion in this way:

1. set the FK of child entity to null
2. delete the child entity

So if you enforce the not-null constraint on the database level, you will have to manually delete the entity from the DB.

Comment: seems strange to me...are you sure there isn't at least a simple workaround not involving explicitely deleting the child entity?

Comment: I'm not sure on this one. You could try to disable the not-null constraint and switch show_sql to true. Run the same test and see how does the hibernate behave

Comment: Yep, it seems hibernate sets to null the FK...now I was wondering..is there a way to intercept this event and skip it so to go to the actual delete?

Comment: I don't think so. You can delete the instance instead.